# Subthreshold Operation for Beta Multiplier Circuit

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, analog, oscillator, cadence

I am currently in the process of designing a Beta Multiplier Circuit using 120 nm technology, and want to run the circuit in subthreshold operation with (Vgs < 4*Vthermal).

Below are some captures of the simulation values:

As you can see VGS is about -4 mV (less than 4*Vthermal assuming Vthermal = 25 mV), however VDS is about 18.5 mV which when checking for VDS> VGS - Vth (for saturation) is true.

So here does the second saturation condition even apply, or is it sufficient to assume that since Vgs < 4 V*thermal which is <Vth (Vth = 170 mV the transistors are in saturation.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the equation for the drain current in subthreshold region:

\$I_d = KI_0 \cdot e^{\frac{V_{GS} - V_{TH}}{\eta V_T}} \left[1 - e^{-\frac{V_{DS}}{V_T}}\right]
\$
where \$I_0 = \mu C_{ox} (\eta - 1) V_T^2\$ and \$ K =W/L\$

As you can see, if \$ V_{DS}\$ is large enough compared to the thermal voltage \$ V_T\$, or \$ V_{DS} \geq 4V_{T} \$, then the drain current can be approximated as the equation below and does not depend on the drain-source voltage (saturation).

\$I_d ≈ KI_0 \cdot e^{\frac{V_{GS} - V_{TH}}{\eta V_T}}
\$